# Jquery validator form

Tags: jquery, forms, customvalidator

I am currently doing a small form with jquery, the grace of this form is that when an error of that type is missed, I send it in the html and put it in a small div that has each input below, according to the type of error that jump, now I have the problem of duplicates and that the error that corresponds is not added

```js
$('form.registerForm').submit(function() {
    var f = $(this).find('.form-group'),
      ferror = false,
      emailExp = /^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i;
      var p1 = $('#password1').val();
      var p2 = $('#password2').val();
      

      f.children('input').each(function() { // run all inputs
      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');
      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {

          case 'password':
            if ( p1 != p2 ) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              
              f.find('.validation').text("Errno password");
              
            }
          break;

          case 'name':
            if ( !isNaN(i.val()) ) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              alert(f);
              f.find('.validation').text("Errno no numbers");     
            }
            break;


          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              f.find('.validation').text("Errno needed");
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              f.find('.validation').text("Errno long");
            }
            break;

          case 'email':
            if (!emailExp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              f.find('.validation').text("Errno email ");
            }
            break;

          case 'checked':
            if (!i.attr('checked')) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              f.find('.validation').text("Errno checker");
            }
            break;


          case 'regexp':
            exp = new RegExp(exp);
            if (!exp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              f.find('.validation').text("Errno regexp");

              
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'Passwords repetidas') : '')).show('blind');
      }

    });

    if (ferror) return false;
    else var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "contactform/contactform.php",
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
        // alert(msg);
        if (msg == 'OK') {
          $("#sendmessage").addClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").removeClass("show");
          $('.contactForm').find("input, text").val("");
        } else {
          $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
          $('#errormessage').html(msg);
        }

      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" role="form" class="registerForm">
    <div id="sendmessage">You did the register!</div>
    <div id="errormessage"></div>
    <ul class="contact-list">
        <li class="form-group">
            <label><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i> Email </label> 
            <input type="email" class="form_input" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="" />
            <div class="validation"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="form-group">
            <label><i class="icon-edit"></i> Password </label>
            <input type="password" class="form_input" name="password" id="password1" placeholder="Contraseña" data-rule="password" data-msg="" />
            <div class="validation"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="form-group">
            <label><i class="icon-edit"></i> Repeat password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form_input" name="password" id="password2" placeholder="Repite la contraseña" data-rule="password" data-msg="" />
            <div class="validation"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="form-group">
            <label><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Name </label> 
            <input type="text" class="form_input" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre" data-rule="name" data-msg="" />
            <div class="validation"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="form-group">
            <label><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Surname </label> 
            <input type="text" class="form_input" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Introduce tus apellidos" data-rule="name" data-msg="" />
            <div class="validation"></div>
            </li>
        <li class="last">
            <button class="btn btn-large btn-theme" type="submit" id="send">Register</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

My fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ho8crseu/

Comment: What do you mean by `now I have the problem of duplicates and that the error that corresponds is not added`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your validation logic, you need to update the `data-msg` value for each input when detected an error, instead of update the html text of the `$('.validation')` div directly.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  //Contact
  $('form.registerForm').submit(function() {
    var f = $(this).find('.form-group'),
      ferror = false,
      emailExp = /^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i;
      var p1 = $('#password1').val();
      var p2 = $('#password2').val();
      

      f.children('input').each(function() { // run all inputs
      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');
      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {

          case 'password':
            if ( !p1 || !p2 || p1 != p2 ) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              i.attr("data-msg", "Errno password");
              
            }
          break;

          case 'name':
            if ( !isNaN(i.val()) ) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              //alert(f);
              i.attr("data-msg", "Errno no numbers");     
            }
            break;

          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              i.attr("data-msg", "Errno needed");
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              i.attr("data-msg", "Errno long");
            }
            break;

          case 'email':
            if (!emailExp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              i.attr("data-msg", "Errno email ");
            }
            break;

          case 'checked':
            if (!i.attr('checked')) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              i.attr("data-msg", "Errno checker");
            }
            break;


          case 'regexp':
            exp = new RegExp(exp);
            if (!exp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
              i.attr("data-msg", "Errno regexp");
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'Passwords repetidas') : '')).show('blind');
      }

    });

    if (ferror) return false;
    else var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "contactform/contactform.php",
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
        // alert(msg);
        if (msg == 'OK') {
          $("#sendmessage").addClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").removeClass("show");
          $('.contactForm').find("input, text").val("");
        } else {
          $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
          $('#errormessage').html(msg);
        }

      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- start contact form -->
<form action="" method="post" role="form" class="registerForm">
  <div id="sendmessage">You did the register!</div>
  <div id="errormessage"></div>
  <ul class="contact-list">
    <li class="form-group">
      <label><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i> Email </label> 
      <input type="email" class="form_input" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="" />
      <div class="validation"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="form-group">
      <label><i class="icon-edit"></i> Password </label>
      <input type="password" class="form_input" name="password" id="password1" placeholder="Contraseña" data-rule="password" data-msg="" />
      <div class="validation"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="form-group">
      <label><i class="icon-edit"></i> Repeat password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form_input" name="password" id="password2" placeholder="Repite la contraseña" data-rule="password" data-msg="" />
      <div class="validation"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="form-group">
      <label><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Name </label> 
      <input type="text" class="form_input" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre" data-rule="name" data-msg="" />
      <div class="validation"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="form-group">
      <label><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Surname </label> 
      <input type="text" class="form_input" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Introduce tus apellidos" data-rule="name" data-msg="" />
      <div class="validation"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="last">
      <button class="btn btn-large btn-theme" type="submit" id="send">Register</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>

<!-- end contact form -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the right context.  Change your code like this:

```
f.children('input').each(function() { // run all inputs
  var i = $(this); // current input
  var parent = i.parent();
```

Now when you set your errors you do it like this:

```
case 'email':
        if (!emailExp.test(i.val())) {
          ferror = ierror = true;
          parent.find('.validation').text("Errno email ");
        }
        break;
```